# Handle HttpError with custom headers in React Admin

Tags: react-admin, http-error

I'm using custom headers as specified [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md):

```js
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);
```

(Also this example fails because DELETE headers are not set, as reported [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5452), but I believe that's another issue)

When API responds with error code and JSON: `{status:500, message:"Internal error"}`,
`fetchUtils` gives `Promise` with `HttpError` as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/dataProvider/fetch.ts#L50).

I get correct notification and my understanding is that the `HttpError` should be handled in `AuthProvider - checkError` but that never happens and React-Admin throws `Unhandled Rejection (HttpError)` pointing to `fetchUtils`.

This is my `checkError`:

```js
checkError: (error) => {
    const status = error.status;
    if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
      localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
      localStorage.removeItem("permissions");
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: authProvider.checkError() does nothing in your case because you're throwing an error with HTTP status 500, and it only looks for status 401 and 403

Comment: @FrançoisZaninotto Thanks for the comment. It should resolve if status is not 401 or 403. Right? Why is it unhandled and how to handle it?